# returning string in method and changing the global variable

Tags: java

What im doing is trying to change the variable postFix from the method append.... but am having no luck... at the end of my main method i have a print and at the end of my append method i have a print... and when i run the program they do not match.... and the program is completely by passing what im attempting to do in append. why is this? is it because im returning it to a method and not main?

```
//MAIN 
    public class stack{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

String line = null;
String postFix = "";
int valOfStack = 0;
int icp,isp = 0;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("p4a.dat"));
    char[] array;   
    array = new char[100];
    line = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("infix: "+line);
    int length = line.length();
        System.out.println("length: "+length);
         //char num = line.charAt(0);
    Stack stack = new Stack();
        //stack.push(num);
        //System.out.println(stack.top());
```

........   continued

```
  else if(word.contains("+")){
                  System.out.println("ya we in// charAt - "+i);
                      operatorJob(word,stack,valOfStack,postFix);

              }

              else if(word.contains("*")){
                  System.out.println("ya we in// charAt - "+i);
                operatorJob(word,stack,valOfStack,postFix);

              }

                  else if(word.contains("/")){
                  System.out.println("ya we in// charAt - "+i);
                operatorJob(word,stack,valOfStack,postFix);

              }

             else if(word.contains("^")){
                  System.out.println("ya we in// charAt - "+i);
                operatorJob(word,stack,valOfStack,postFix);

              }

//OPERATOR JOB
    public static int operatorJob(String word,Stack stack,int valOfStack,String postFix){
        //if word is an operator +-*/^or(

                if(stack.isEmpty()){
                    stack.push(word);
                valOfStack+=1;
                }

                else{
                String inStack =stack.top().toString();
                int isp = assignISPval(inStack);
                int icp = assignICPval(word);
                System.out.println(icp+" "+isp);
                    if(isp >= icp)
                    append(postFix,stack);

                }
//METHOD THAT IS RETURNING
public static String append(String postFix,Stack stack){
                    String operator = stack.pop().toString();
                    postFix = postFix.concat(operator);
                    System.out.println("a "+postFix);
                        return postFix;     
                }//end append
```

Comment: The code is a bit too long to work out exactly where you are having your issue, but `append(postFix,stack);` looks wrong as you are throwing away the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of `append(postFix,stack);` to a variable

try something like

```
  String newValue = append(postFix,stack);
  System.out.println (newValue);
```

Comment: ok now how do i change the variable postFix that is in main... do i have to return it again from my operatorJob method?

Comment: if you made the `postFix` a field arather than a local variable you would not have to worry about returning the values, you could just `act` on the class field directly.

Comment: @cmehmen If my answer helped you, you should upvote it at the very least (it's on the upper left of every answer). And mark one of the answers in this question as correct.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Scary Wombat's response:

When you call append, you have two string references (one in operator job and one in append) called `postfix`. They both point to the same object. When you assign the the append value of `postfix` to the result of `postFix.concat(operator)` the append value of postfix now points to the correct object but the one in job operator does not. To make the `joboperator`reference point to the same value, you have to set it in `joboperator`, which is what Scary Wombat's code does.